# Exception in 'create linked table' using H2 database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, h2

i'm using [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)(h2-1.4.186.jar) database for a java application. I have created 2 databases, one is a support database that i use for many tasks.
In one of these tasks i need a table( created as a select f.field,h.field from table f join table h ecc...) from the other database. So I have used 'create linked table'. If I execute a query from the browser console it works, but if I do it in a java method it doesn't work. Here is the method:

```
private void createTable()
{
    
    String linkedTable="create force linked table if not exists "+TABLE_NAME+"('org.h2.Driver','jdbc:h2:../GLOBALDB/general','user','pass','("+getQuery()+")')";
    try{
        
        Connection conn=GenericDatabaseConnections.getConnectionDBThreads();
        Statement sta=conn.createStatement();
        
        try{
            
            sta.execute(linkedTable);
            sta.execute("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME);
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        sta.close();
        conn.close();
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

and I get the following exceptions:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error accessing linked table with SQL statement "SELECT * FROM (select * from film) T", cause: "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table ""(select * from film)(org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table """"FILM"""" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM (select * from film) T WHERE 1=0 [42102-186])"" not found [42102-186]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM film [90111-186]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.table.TableLink.wrapException(TableLink.java:462)
    at org.h2.index.LinkedIndex.find(LinkedIndex.java:127)
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.find(BaseIndex.java:127)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:159)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:329)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:574)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:686)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:322)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:290)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:36)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:90)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:197)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:179)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
    at TableManager.createTable(TableManager.java:335)
    at TableManager.task(TableManager.java:33)
    at TaskManager.startTask(TaskManager.java:38)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "(select * from film)(org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table ""FILM"" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM (select * from film) T WHERE 1=0 [42102-186])" not found [42102-186]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.table.TableLink.readMetaData(TableLink.java:196)
    at org.h2.table.TableLink.connect(TableLink.java:98)
    at org.h2.table.TableLink.<init>(TableLink.java:78)
    at org.h2.schema.Schema.createTableLink(Schema.java:607)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateLinkedTable.update(CreateLinkedTable.java:77)
    at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.execute(MetaRecord.java:58)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:732)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:266)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:260)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:60)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:167)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:145)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:128)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:26)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:347)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:92)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at databaseconnection.GenericDatabaseConnections.getConnectionDBThreads(GenericDatabaseConnections.java:46)
    at TableManager.createTable(TableManager.java:329)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "FILM" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM (select * from film) T WHERE 1=0 [42102-186]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1235)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1874)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1983)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1868)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1689)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1159)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1874)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1983)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1868)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1689)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1677)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:433)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:305)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:277)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:242)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:446)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:388)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1189)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.table.TableLink.readMetaData(TableLink.java:173)
    ... 24 more
```

Finally if I do it in java when the browser console is opened it works.
How I can fix it?
P.S. sorry for my bad english

Comment: "Table not found" usually means it's the wrong database. Try using an absolute path, for example `jdbc:h2:/data/GLOBALDB/general` not `jdbc:h2:../GLOBALDB/general`.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Thanks for your comment...I've tried using the absolute path  ( `"jdbc:h2:E:\\Eclipse\\workspace\\H2\\GLOBALDB\\general" `) but I got the same exception